# Evaluate the difference quotient for $f(x)=x^3$

Tags: calculus, functions

Evaluate the difference quotient for $f(x) = x^3$.

For any function $y = f(x)$, the difference quotient is defined as:  $$\frac{f(a + h) − f(a)}h$$

Our function is $f(x) = x^3$. Therefore, $f(a) =$ ?

What is $f(a)$ equal to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean $f(x) = x^3$, in which case

$$f(a) = a^3$$

and $$f(a + h) = (a + h)^3$$.

To simplify the quotient, just expand and cancel until you can't.

Comment: Yes, it's a to the 3rd (I'm new here, how do I use formatting?)

Comment: @Grey See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I got f(a) = 3a^2+3ah+h^2 which isn't correct answer. What do I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Grey That is the correct answer.

Comment: It's an online homework and it doesn't accept it a correct answer. It says  the correct answer is f(a)=a^3  :)

Comment: @Grey Oh, I'm sorry. I misread your comment. The correct answer for $f(a)$ is $a^3$ as I said in my original answer; the fully simplified difference quotient is $3a^2 + 3ah + h^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We are given that $f(x) = x^3$. Note that the $x$ is just a placeholder. So if we want to figure out what $f(\text{stuff})$ evaluates to, we just replace every instance of $x$ with $\text{stuff}$. Hence, we know that:

- $f(a) = a^3$
- $f(a+h) = (a+h)^3$

Comment: I got f(a) = 3a^2+3ah+h^2 which isn't correct answer. What do I do wrong? Thanks.